# Getting a value from an array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array:

```
address => [{"data"=>{"zip"=>"60628", "state"=>"IL", "city"=>"chicago", "street"=>"123 Main St. Apt 2"}, "primary"=>true}]
```

I want to show each piece in the right format on my view like:

```
123 Main St. Apt 2
Chicago, IL 60628
```

I am having trouble getting the logic correct to show this.

Where should this logic go, as a method in my model or in the actual view?

I tried:

```
<% @applicant.address.map{|x| x[:data]}.each do |address| %>
  <%= address.street %><br><%= address.city %>, <%= address.state %> <%= address.zip %> <br>
      <% end %>
```

but got:

```
=> [{"zip"=>"60628", "state"=>"IL", "city"=>"chicago", "street"=>"123 main st Apt 2"}]
```

Comment: what you show comes from an `erb` view ? could you show it with the surrounding `erb` tags please ?

Comment: Yes its an erb view, unsure what you mean by erb tags?

Comment: sorry `<%=`, `<%`, `%>`, ...

Comment: what happens if you change `y.street` to `y[:street]`?

Comment: @iamjhu nothing same output as my effort.

Comment: @VonD I updated the question with tags

Comment: `address=>[...]` is not a Ruby object. You need to delete `address=>` (or better, change to `address = [...]`, so that readers can reference the variable `address` without having to define it). Perhaps that's obvious, but you can save yourself some downvotes by taking my advice.

Comment: tags look ok. as iamjhu pointed it should be y['street'] and so on. But anyway it's strange that it does not raise an error and that it returns the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map gives you a new array and if you use hashes you need to access the values with the hash[:key] or hash["key"] operator, try this:

```
<% @applicant.address.each do |address_hash| %>
  <% address = address_hash["data"] %>
  <%= address["street"] %><br><%= address["city"] %>, <%= address["state"] %> <%= address["zip"] %> <br>
<% end %>
```

But if I were you , I'd put the data in an array of structs, it's more readable.

In your model or helper:

```
address = Struct.new(:street, :city, :state, :zip)
address.street = ..
...
@addresses << address
etc
```

In your view:

```
<% @addresses.each do |address| %>
  <%= address.street %><br><%= address.city %>, <%= address.state %> <%= address.zip %> <br>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your first question something like this should suffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'ostruct'

address = [
  {
    'data'    => { 
                   'zip'    => '60628',
                   'state'  => 'IL',
                   'city'   => 'chicago',
                   'street' =>'123 Main St. Apt 2'
                 },
    'primary' => true
   }
]

class AddressPresenter
  def initialize(address)
     @address = OpenStruct.new(address)
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@address.street} \n#{@address.city} #{@address.state} #{@address.zip}"
  end
end

address.each do |a|
  puts AddressPresenter.new(a['data'])
end
```

Now, for the second question, I would implement a **Presenter** class whose only goal is to "present" the data in whatever format you need in the view, this allows you to keep your views with 0 presentation logic. So in this case the class `AddressPresenter` could be reworked to return in the `to_s` the right HTML you need in your view. And you would do something like:

```
<% @applicant.address.each do |address| %>
  <%= AddressPresenter.new(address['data']).to_s %>
<% end %>
```

By having a separated presenter class, you get the following benefits:

1. Your models don't worry about how to present/render stuff because that's not their job
2. You can test this presenter to confirm it returns whatever you're expecting in the view
3. Your views don't contain any complicated logic

Comment: I like your solution about the Presenter class. I have more logic then I would like in my view. I may use your solution in a refactoring of my project. Thanks